# Executar comandos ao abrir programa

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Bom, estou tentando executar vários comandos ao abrir o programa, mas isso impede que o mesmo seja mostrado no tempo desejado, já que ele executa todos pra depois mostrar.
Estou tentando executar tais comandos no OnShow do formulário. Já que tem um For, demora bastante pra abrir.
Tem algum modo de dar um delay entre o tempo que o programa é mostrado e os comandos?
Fazendo com que todos sejam executados depois que o programa for mostrado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o componente `TTimer`.

1. Adicione-o ao form;
2. sete sua propriedade `Enable` para `false`.
3. Informe um tempo relativo para o form ser exibido, aproximadamente 2 segundos = 2000 milésimos na propriedade `Interval`;

   O valor padrão dessa propriedade é 1000 (1000 milésimos de segundo = 1 segundo). Mudando para 2000 será dois segundos.
4. Na última linha do método `OnShow` do form, sete a propriedade `Enable` para `true`:

   **Exemplo**:

   ```
   timer1.Enable := true;
   ```
5. Agora você precisa passar os seus comandos para o evento `OnTimer` do componente `TTimer`. Para isso, dê um duplo clique no componente que então será criado o método padrão `OnTimer`.
6. Mude os seus comandos que estão no `OnShow` do form para esse novo
   método criado.

Pronto!
Após o tempo determinado, como os 2 segundos, os comandos começarão a ser executados.

---

### Detalhes sobre o componente `TTimer`:

O componente `TTimer` tem um evento chamado `OnTimer` que é o principal recurso desse componente e é o que foi descrito nessa resposta para ser utilizado.

Mas, o componente `TTimer` não executa esse método apenas um vez, mas sim indeterminadas vezes, de tempos em tempos, em intervalos de tempos definidos pelo valor de tempo setado em sua propriedade `Interval`.

Logo, para ter o método sendo executado apenas uma vez é preciso desativá-lo logo ao executar pela primeira vez, assim:

```
// assinatura fictícia do método / exemplo
procedure FormFicticio.Timer1OnTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Timer1.Enable := false;  // <-- isso deve ser feito

  // Os demais comandos que deseja executar
end;
```

Fazendo isso ele será executado apenas uma vez.
Caso contrário executará sempre, conforme já mencionado.

Comment: Percebi, rs. Resolvido.